# How can I tell what files a process has open?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, process

I have a daemon process and I want to know what files it has open (and ideally what its CWD is).  Is there any shell command that can tell me that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do love `lsof`, but I think it's overkill for a simple question like this.  The `/proc` filesystem contains everything you want to know.  Perhaps an example would be best:

```
# ps ax|grep tail
 7196 pts/4    S+     0:00 tail -f /var/log/messages
 8773 pts/0    R+     0:00 grep tail
# ls -l /proc/7196/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 insyte insyte 0 2009-07-29 19:05 /proc/7196/cwd -> /home/insyte
# ls -l /proc/7196/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 insyte insyte 64 2009-07-29 19:05 0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 insyte insyte 64 2009-07-29 19:05 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 insyte insyte 64 2009-07-29 19:02 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lr-x------ 1 insyte insyte 64 2009-07-29 19:05 3 -> /var/log/messages
```

So as you can see, the `/proc/$PID` directory contains a symlink called "cwd" that links the the CWD of the process.  The same is true for the open filedescriptors listed in `/proc/$PID/fd`.

The `/proc/$PID` hierarchy contains a wealth of information about all running processes.  Worth poking around in!

Comment: lsof is easier.

Answer (score 13):

If you have the command **lsof** available [whcih most *nix flavors do] you would use:

```
lsof -p NNN
```

to list files open by process NNN. I haven't used BSD in a while but from memory **fuser** is a close parallel to lsof.

I'm not sure of a command to find the **cwd** of a process but on Linux cwd is symlinked into the /proc directory of the process ie. /proc/NNN/cwd.

Comment: On Ubuntu, lsof comes with the lsof package. I don't think that it's installed by default.

Answer (score 4):

if you know the processes PID, you can just issue an

```
lsof | grep YOURPID
```

Quick and easy to remember.

or

```
lsof -c yourprogramexecutable
```

Comment: What's wrong with lsof -p PID?

Comment: Nothing. It's only that the grep pipe is burned into my brain for at least 15 years now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try lsof if it's installed on your system

D

Answer (score 0):

This may also help, using proc file-system you can do:

```
readlink proc_sample/proc/<YOUR_PID>/fd/*
```

Don't forget to replace `<YOUR_PID>` with the desired process id.